# verilog coding style for synthesizable code

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I coded something like the following:

```
always @(state or i1 or i2 or i3 or i4) begin
next = 5'bx;
err = 0; n_o1 = 1;
o2 = 0; o3 = 0; o4 = 0;
case (state) // synopsys full_case parallel_case
IDLE: begin
if (!i1) next = IDLE;
else if ( i2) next = S1;
else if ( i3) next = S2;
else next = ERROR;
end
S1: begin
if (!i2) next = S1;
else if ( i3) next = S2;
else if ( i4) next = S3;
else next = ERROR;**strong text**
...
```

My manager, of course I don't want to argue with him before I have some strong argument, but he reviewed my code and said writing

```
next = 5'bx;
err = 0; n_o1 = 1;
o2 = 0; o3 = 0; o4 = 0;
```

in a combinational logic without putting the right side in the sensitivity list will cause problems in synthesis.By not having these 3 lines, I need to explicitly write the else part inside each individual case, and he said yes.

I am wondering is there anything wrong with this coding style? And will it cause a synthesis problem or any sort of problem(maybe some version or old synthesis tool won't synthesize?) by initializing these values in the combinational logic? What he said does make sense to me and I actually never thought about it because he said this is software logic, and every wire gets its initial value from the logic before it with the initial condition. I told him school taught us this, he was like school cares less any synthesis but industry does.

Thank you for your help! Guess I am not trying to convince him anything even I have a answer, since the team need to stick with one style anyways, but i am confused by him since I have seen others doing this all the time and he is also a guy with tons of experience, so...confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your boss means by "software logic" is that your coding style requires the designer to think sequentially. In other words, when I read your `always` block, I am first forced to think about all the values being initialized to their default values, then I must evaluate the case logic. In reality, the logic will synthesize into the equivalent of a `default` case. This causes a disparity between the logic that represents the RTL and the logic of how I evaluate your expression in my mind. If you know what your doing, then this should be fine *most of the time*. But you are working for a company, so your code should be considerate of the other engineers working on a project. Each different team in the design flow is going to view the same logic through a potentially different lens (for example, the physical design team is not concerned with Verilog but the synthesized RTL). If we write our Verilog to reflect the final RTL (i.e. "hardware logic"), then everyone is analyzing the logic in a similar fashion. If I look at an output in a circuit and I know all the values of the inputs at a given time step, then I can visually trace the output through the circuit and determine its value without giving any consideration to the other logic. Your Verilog code should be written in the same way.

To summarize, your initialization statements are nothing more than another case in the selection mux in the RTL. So, you should write it that way. Use a `default` case and explicitly assign every output of the block in each case. This is generally considered best practice. It may not be the most clever or elegant way to write Verilog, but it is the most readable and results in far fewer errors (and in industry, people are more concerned with design verification to reduce costs than the cleverness of Verilog).

Also, as @dave_59 brought up, if you use the `full_case` Synopsis directive, then it will create default output drivers for you where the outputs are set to "don't cares." This is not a result that anyone wants, and it would be flagged by the verification team. To fix it, you would need to make sure every output is being assigned by adding them to all the cases like your boss mentioned. If you are forced to do this anyways, then `full_case` is redundant because you have explicitly made the case statement full. As for older synthesis tools, I don't see that being as big of an issue for this particular subject, but it is a consideration that is always given in industry. What would be more of an issue is if your company has configured downstream tools to force older constructs in an effort to reduce verification costs.

Trust your manager's experience on this issue. Coding style in industry is largely affected by collaboration with other engineers, costs, and legacy than by technical details. This is where your manager's experience will be valuable.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Follow up: my initialization will assign the variables to 0 at the beginning even if a non-default case is picked and the if statement inside that case is not triggered. So if i have a default case, if i enter the case once and the if executes the variable is changed to 1, and the next time i enter that case,  if the control signal in my if has changed and the if is not executed, the variable will keep its value from last change which will be 1, the default case is not executed. But my coding will change the variable to 0 in this case . So i guess there is a difference?

Comment: Yes that's correct which is what I was getting at when I mentioned being able to easily determine the output value. Due to your coding style, I cannot determine the output knowing the previous value and current control signals alone which is typically how people approach hardware logic.

Comment: I see what you are getting at

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should be using `always @(*)` from Verilog-2001 or even better `always_comb` from SystemVerilog so the sensitivity list get constructed automatically for you.

The problem with your code is the use of the `full case` synthesis pragma as described in [this paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1999Boston_FullParallelCase.pdf). Your coding style removes the need for full case as long as you are sure you made assignments to every variable in the `always` block for all possible flows through the block.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I know a always(*) should be used. So your answer is that it is fine to have the variables initialized on the top of the case statement which will not cause any problem? And by the way, this coding style is exactly copied from the man you just mentioned but a different paper from him "State Machine Coding Styles for Synthesis." I read his papers(include the one you mentioned) as reference.  Since I told my boss to use(\*) when he said the sensitivity list is incomplete, but he seems to have problem with initializing the variables

Comment: He saw this and said "i don't appreciate this style since this is like software logic" I am like what... this is what my school taught me...he wants every if to followed by a else so no latches for older synthesis tools

Comment: this style is ok and is widely used. one thing is undesired though: `next = 5'bx;` Is better to assign a known value there or you might have verification/synthesis issues.